# In this ASP.NET MVC 3 app, what am I missing to get unobtrusive client-side validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive-validation

I need help figuring out how to succeed in implementing unobtrusive client-side validation of a field in my ASP.NET MVC 3 app. I can see that unobtrusive client-side validation *is* basically enabled, since MVC generates related HTML.

What I want to achieve in this case is to have validation of input to the `Bugs` editor (i.e., the corresponding `<input>` element) as I type, for testing purposes I've set the property's max length to 2. When I test, I can tell that validation does not currently take place, so something is at least missing. *So, the success criteria for this question is working client-side validation of the `Bugs` form field*.

I can see one possible problem in the generated HTML: The `Verbose` property is *not* marked as `Required` in the model, but its corresponding `<input>` still gets the `dataval=true` attribute for instance, *whereas the `<input>` for `Bugs` does not*. Shouldn't it be the other way around, as fields with validation rules should get `dataval=true`, to enable unobtrusive validation?

The code that should be relevant to understanding the case follows, please let me know if more info is required:

`Options.cs`:

```
public class Options
{
    [Required, StringLength(2)]
    public string Bugs;
    public bool Verbose;
}
```

`Options.cshtml`:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="options-form">
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Options</legend>
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bugs)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bugs)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bugs)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Verbose)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Verbose)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Verbose)
      </div>
   </fieldset>
  }
</div>
```

The two editors (for `Bugs` and `Verbose`) are rendered as follows:

```
<div id="options-form">
<form action="/Options" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Options</legend>
      <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Bugs">Bugs</label>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" id="Bugs" name="Bugs" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Bugs" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Verbose">Verbose</label>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Boolean field is required." id="Verbose" name="Verbose" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Verbose" type="hidden" value="false" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Verbose" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `Bugs` and `Verbose` are public fields in this code, not properties.  I'm not sure that has anything to do with it though.

Comment: @NickLarsen Hah, that's all it took! Please submit it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Bugs` and `Verbose` are public fields in this code, not properties. Make them properties and that should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Define `get;` and `set;` for both `Bugs` and `Verbose` properties. That will not just correct(add) validation, but in the future, model binder will be able to bind models back from form fields on server.

And regarding required attribute for `Verbose`. That is because of implicit required validation for value types taking place. string is nullable, so it is not required if you do not set `Required` attribute on it explicitely - so Bugs stays without required. But `bool` cannot be `null` by nature of c#, so mvc automatically adds `Required` attribute to it. You can control that with

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem recently (unobtrusive client-side validation didn't work in IE but worked in the other browsers though). The reason was in jQuery version. I rolled back from jQuery 1.6.x version to the version 1.5.2 an it started to work.